# Set -noverify flag in java code

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I would like to set -noverify as a VM argument through java code. I could not find any resource online to help with this.

If I use `System.setProperty(..,..)` , what do I set as the value or perhaps the key?

I have tried using `System.property("Xverify","none")` but this doesn't seem to work.

**Note**: This is just to run some test cases. I am turning off byte code verification because of this issue - [link](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/375)

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you ever want this?

Comment: VerifyError while using PowerMockito. This is the solution for it, but I want to put it in code.

Comment: `VerifyError` definitely means that the program works wrong. Turning verification off in this case is dangerous and is likely to cause JVM crash. Never trust an application or library that throws `VerifyError`!

Comment: [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321205/jvm-crash-problematic-frame-canonicalizerdo-if) of what happens when running with `-noverify` (even though the library developers promised that this option would not harm).

Comment: I know this. This is for a test case only.

Comment: *"I know I'm doing wrong, but I still want to do this"* - I'm afraid you won't get adequate answers with this point.

Comment: BTW, the link to PowerMock issue suggests the different solution - to upgrade Javassist library.

Comment: Obviously, there is no legal way to turn off verification programmatically. Otherwise this would seriosly compromise the security and the integrity of Java platform.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade the javassist version.  @apangin Thanks for clearing this out.  Please post this as an answer and I will close this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me summarize comments in this answer.

- It is dangerous to turn the bytecode verification off, especially when you know the application throws `VerifyError`. This means that the application generates invalid bytecode, and when JVM executes it, the results are unpredictable. For example, JVM may crash like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321205/jvm-crash-problematic-frame-canonicalizerdo-if?noredirect=1&lq=1).
- There is no legal way to turn the bytecode verification off programmatically. Otherwise this would be a serious security breach that allows to run unsafe code without explicit permissions.
- [The link](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/375) to PowerMock issue you've mentioned confirms that there was **a bug** in Javassist library. The right way to solve the issue is to update to newer Javassist version where this bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use "-Xverify:none" as vm argument.
It is recommended not to use -Xverify:none in production environment.

For those of you unfamiliar with bytecode verification, it is simply part of the JVM's classloading process that checks the code for certain dangerous and disallowed behavior. You can (but shouldn't) disable this protection on many JVMs by adding -Xverify:none

Please find the complete details about the side affect of using this flag - https://blogs.oracle.com/buck/entry/never_disable_bytecode_verification_in

Comment: How do you propose to set Xverify to none in code? I have tried setting it using System.setProperty but it doesn't work that way.