# Java verify error Expected stackmap frame

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Anyone knows how to fix this? 
Eclipse Mars 2
Java 1.8.0_151
Tomcat 8.0

Nov 05, 2017 7:57:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 29

Exception Details:

Location:
    com/xxxxx/xxxxV1(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response; @12: aload_0

Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.

Bytecode:

0x0000000: 2b4d b204 732a 2a2c b804 794e 2a2c 2db8

0x0000010: 049c 01b2 0473 b804 a0c0 010c b03a 04b8

0x0000020: 04a7 1904 b204 732d b604 ab19 04bf

Exception Handler Table:
    bci [12, 29] => handler: 29

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -noverify in your JVM properties. It's JVM verification which is throwing this error.

Comment: -1. It's a very bad idea to turn off bytecode verification. This may lead to unpredictable issues, even to JVM crash like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40321205/3448419). When JVM executes a Java program, it relies on certain invariants on the bytecode level. VerifyError means there is a bug which breaks these invariants.

Comment: @apangin It's sometimes necessary when rewriting bytecode to be used by another JVM. Edge case, I know.