# JVM Crashed with Internal Error safepoint.cpp:687 Deadlock in safepoint code. Should have called back to the VM before blocking

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm-hotspot

Tomcat is crashing unexpectedly randomly with hs_err file generated.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (safepoint.cpp:687), pid=14568, tid=0x0000000000002edc
fatal error: Deadlock in safepoint code.  Should have called back to the VM before blocking.

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Failed to write core dump. Minidump has been disabled from the command line
```

A week ago we were getting Invalid Cert Authority Warning on chrome, so the devOps team updated some
ports and SSL configurations in server.xml including:

- --> changed to shutdown="SECURITY"
  <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" -->   redirectPort="443" changed to 8443
- <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" -->   redirectPort="443" changed to 8443
- <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" --> Port changed from 443 to 8443 and Keystore file also updated.
- Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" --> Port changed from 8009 to 8004

I am not sure which thread is causing the deadlock and why.

I am attaching two hs_err files the crash is internal with different stacktrace.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ieJ6wZKIOVPe-RJexvUNSZUDQ4Us6wzf?usp=sharing

I searched on internet and some suggestions are to update the JDK, I can not update the JDK as our application is old and would start causing compatibility issues.

The code i found from where the error is generating in openJDK
https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/openjdk-8/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/safepoint.cpp.shtml

Comment: Upgrading to JDK 9 might not be an alternative, but you should be able to upgrade to a more recent JDK 8 release. It should be compatible with JDK 8u181

Comment: There are two obvious issues visible in crash dumps: 1) too old JDK version; 2) `-Xverify:none` JVM option, which essentially makes Java Runtime unprotected from invalid bytecode and may cause unpredictable behavior including [JVM crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321205/jvm-crash-problematic-frame-canonicalizerdo-if).

Comment: I analyzed the hotspot file, looks like when garbage collection running the JVM is crashing. Added GC1 variables to java options lets monitor and i will update.